# How can i add default value when i want to create new table via console

Tags: cakephp, migration, default-value, cakephp-3.4, phinx

I have shell command like this. Tell me please, how can i add default value to this query ?

```
bin/cake bake migration CreateProducts name:string description:text created modified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, it's not supported, the column definition syntax is:

```
fieldName:fieldType?[length]:indexType:indexName
```

If you want to specify a default, then you need to add that to the migration file manually using the `default` option of the `addColumn()` method, like:

```
$table->addColumn('name', 'string', [
    'default' => 'default value',
    // ...
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Migrations > Columns Definition](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html#columns-definition)**
- **[Cookbook > Migrations > Creating a table](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html#creating-a-table)**